# How to upload an excel file into S3 bucket using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, axlsx

In our rails 6 project I want to upload excel file into S3 bucket and send file link to email and provide download xls feature from email. Please help me.

I have generated the excel file using the code below, and also set S3 configuration in our project

```
 xlsx = GenerateSpreadsheetService.new(all_data, file_name).call
```

Now my question is that how to upload the above excel file into S3 bucket and send file link to email and provide download xls feature from email

```
class ImportCsvDataJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default


  def perform(file_name, column)
    begin
      keywords = []
      all_data = []

      file_path = get_file_path(file_name)
      spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(file_path)
      (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        keywords << {"language_code": "en", "location_code": 2840, "keyword": "allintitle: #{spreadsheet.row(i)}"}
      end

      response = GetTaskService.new(keywords).call 
      response["tasks"].map{|task|
        keyword = task["data"]["keyword"].gsub('allintitle: ','')
        result = GetTaskService.new.get_values(task["id"])
        all_data << {keyword: keyword.to_s, value: result["tasks"][0]["result"][0]["se_results_count"]}
      } 
      ## Create records  
      CsvImport.create(all_data)
      ## Generate excel file
      xlsx = GenerateSpreadsheetService.new(all_data, file_name).call
      ## send email
      SendEmailJob.perform_now(xlsx, file_name) 
      ## remove temp storage file after processing
      File.delete(Rails.root + "public/spreadsheets/#{file_name}")
    rescue Exception => e
      Rails.logger.info "--error-----#{e.message}--"
    end
  end
end
```

```
class GenerateSpreadsheetService
  def initialize(data = [], file_name)
    @data = data
    @file_name = file_name
  end

  def call
    ActionController::Base.new().render_to_string(template: "csv_imports/template.xlsx.axlsx", layout: false, formats: [:axlsx], locals: {:data => @data})
  end
end
```

```
class SendEmailJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(xlsx, file_name)
    SendEmailService.new(xlsx, file_name).call
  end
end
```

```
class SendEmailService
    def initialize(xlsx, file_name)
        @xlsx = xlsx
        @email = "test@example.com"
        @subject = "excel file"
        @file_name = file_name
    end

    def call
        KeywordMailer.send_csv(@email, @subject, @xlsx, @file_name).deliver_now!
    end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code and tell us what specific problem you are having?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, Thanks for comment. I have share all of my code here, Please check now..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### How did I solved this problem?

1. #### Generate excel sheet

```rb
   time = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
   xlsx = GenerateSpreadsheetService.new(all_data, file_name).call
```

2. #### Create an empty directory

```rb
   path = Tempfile.new("data_#{time}.xlsx").path
```

3. #### Write the excel file into this directory

```rb
   file = File.open(path,"wb") {|f| f.write(xlsx) }
   s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: APP_CONFIG["s3_region"], credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(APP_CONFIG["s3_access_key"], APP_CONFIG["s3_secret_key"]))
   obj = s3.bucket(APP_CONFIG["s3_bucket"]).object("data_#{time}.xlsx")
   obj.upload_file(path)
   presigned_url = obj.presigned_url(:put, bucket: APP_CONFIG["s3_bucket"], key: "data_#{time}.xlsx", expires_in: 604800)
```

4. #### save public_url and presigned_url

```rb
   FileUrl.create(key: "data_#{time}.xlsx", file_public_url: obj.public_url, file_presigned_url: presigned_url) if presigned_url.present?
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html

Amazon gives you the answer:

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-west-2')
obj = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key')
obj.upload_file('/path/to/source/file')
```

You simply need to set the region, bucket-name and then the file path on the last line is wherever you store this xls file.  It looks like you're storing it at /public/spreadsheets with some random file name.

Comment: Hi @tgmerritt, Thanks for your comment, 
I would like to know that how to set the path of the file to S3. /public/spreadsheets is a local directory where I stored input excel file for first time, but actually I want to upload the output excel file, which file I am not storing in any directory which is below  

xlsx = GenerateSpreadsheetService.new(all_data, file_name).call

Comment: You should write the file out to some directory first.  If you are trying to create a file and hold it in memory and upload to S3, you're going to have a bad time.  Just make the call() function end with writing the file to disk and immediately queue a task to upload it.